# Are crew members trained equally?

Tags: world-of-tanks

If I have all my crew 100% trained and want to train a new skill, is it better to train them one at a time, or should I train them all in new skill at the same time?

Is the XP shared out equally, or applied to all at once?

How does Elite training affect this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you want to delay that?

ALL crew members receive the same XP after a battle. If your battle got you 400XP, each of 4 crew members gets +400XP, not +100. If your crew member needs 1800XP till next skill level, you need to earn just 1800XP, 9000.

That makes tanks with large crew better for training as you train more crew members at the same time as all of them get the same, full XP.

There are two exceptions to that rule.

- **Elite Training gives double XP** to the crew member with lowest XP at the moment of "upgrade".
- **Crewmen who die during the battle only receive 50%** of the exp awarded.

Let's say your crew is:

```
  Commander: 84500XP
  Gunner:    84200XP
  Driver:    84600XP
  Gunner 1:  83800XP
  Gunner 2:  84100XP
```

You're in an Elite vehicle with Elite Training enabled. You won a battle, earning 400XP. It was the first victory in that vehicle so you received the daily 2x bonus. It's also a vehicle on a special mission list, with mission bonus "triple experience for the crew". During the battle your driver and gunner got killed.

The result:

```
  base 400 x2(first victory) = 800 x3(mission) = 2400

  Commander: 84500XP + 2400 = 86900
  Gunner:    84200XP + (2400/2(killed)) = 85400
  Driver:    84600XP + (2400/2(killed)) = 85800
  Gunner 1:  83800XP + (2400*2(elite))  = 88600
  Gunner 2:  84100XP + 2400             = 86500
```

As you see Gunner 1 got 4800XP thanks to the Elite Training (and starting off with lowest XP in the crew) and it got him ahead of all the rest.

Usually, there is no reason to delay choosing a skill if you only know which one to choose. The golden [+] is of no use, while any of skills that grow with percentage grows by strides in the early stage.

You may consider delaying in two cases:

- If you choose one that works after achieving 100%, that's when you might consider delaying the choice - XP still gets collected, and you can change your mind about what to choose.
- If you plan to retrain your crew for silver to the new tank, losing 10% of the base skill. The XP points accumulated under the golden "+" immediately fills the base skill deficit; to recover your crew from 90 back to 100% you need 39,153 exp and if you collected that many under non-assigned skill, you'll be back to 100% immediately (the XP consumed, obviously).

Comment: Thanks! Your first paragraph cleared up the question ("ALL crew members receive the same XP after a battle. If your battle got you 400XP, each of 4 crew members gets +400XP, not +100."), but the rest illustrates it perfectly.

Comment: I remember reading, that the crew share the XP, so smaller crews are trained faster, as they get a greater share. Is this not correct?

Comment: @Nix: This is not correct, and easily verified with crew members nearing 99% (when you need a few battles to advance 1%). Check your crew's cards, "experience to next level" entry, write it down, finish a battle and check the entry again. Each crew member's entry value will drop by the current battle's earned XP. Also note it would mean crews of low-crew vehicles that are good XP earners (like ELC AMX) would advance at insane pace, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a crew member at 100% you can give him a skill, it does not affect the other members in anyway. Once that skill hits 100%, you can give him another skill.

The experience to distributed to each crew member after a round is even as possible. This is slightly different (and gets messy) when elite training comes into effect. The member with the lowest exp receives extra based on the exp you earned from the match.

a crew member at 100% without a skill will only buffer exp until its dumped into a skill, his battle efficiency wont go beyond base 100%

So whenever you have the ability to get a skill, do so. The experience isn't wasted... but you get a skill!